# Can you link aggregate more than 2 physical connections?

Tags: networking

What are the limitations of the number of physical connections that can be tied together in a single LAC?

Do limitations vary based on hardware type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementations but 8 and 16 are somewhat common numbers. Some Cisco etherchannel devices are limited to 4 active connections, but you can potentially all the ports on the device.